# How to Write Schema with Given Formatting

Tags: xml, xsd

I have to write schemas based on my XML code with the given framework. For example:

- Artist or group: string values; required
- Group members: string value, this can occur once, more than once or not at all
- Genre: string value, must occur at least once per Artist or group; required

I have tried writing a schema but I feel lost...

Code for XML File:

```
<Albums>
<artist personorgroup="person" groupmembernames="N/A" artistorgroupcountry="United States"
    careerBegin="2015" careerend="N/A" artistName="Cardi B" genre="Rap">
    <album albumCategory="Grammy Nominee" albumName="Invasion of Privacy" sku="K315SPR19A"
        type="album">
        <Comment> Absolute trash, it's a travesty this won a Grammy </Comment>

        <Rating> 13/13 </Rating>

        <albumArt> Cardi B.jpg <!-- Found from albumartexchange.com -->
        </albumArt>
        <releases>
            <release release="Invasion of Privacy (clean lyrics)" releasedate="2018-04-05"
                recordlabel="Atlantic (Warner Music imprint), KSR Group"
                recordlabelcatalognumber="N/A" barcodenumber="075679873675" country="US"
                format="Digital Media"> </release>
            <release release="Invasion of Privacy (explicit)"
                releasedate="2018-04-05 / 2018-04-06 / 2018-04-06"
                recordlabel="Atlantic (Warner Music imprint), KSR Group"
                recordlabelcatalognumber="N/A" barcodenumber="075679873682"
                country="XW
                        CA
                        US"
                format="Digital Media"> </release>
        </releases>
        <Songs>
            <song songposition="1" songlength="3:51"
                songcomposersandwriters="Sean Allen / Belcalis Almanzar / Maurice Jordan / Jermaine Preyan / James SwanQo / Anthony Tucker / Robert Williams"
                songName="Get Up 10" sku="K315SPR19A001" albumref="K315SPR19A" type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="2" songlength="4:23"
                songcomposersandwriters="Belcalis Almanzar / Kirsnick Ball / Kiari Cephus / Joshua Cross / Quavious Marshall"
                songName="Drip (feat. Migos)" sku="K315SPR19A002" albumref="K315SPR19A"
                type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="3" songlength="3:01"
                songcomposersandwriters="Belcalis Almanzar / James Foye III / Philip Coleman, Jr. / Austin Owens / Jordan Thorpe"
                songName="Bickenhead" sku="K315SPR19A003" albumref="K315SPR19A" type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="4" songlength="3:43"
                songcomposersandwriters="Belcalis Almanzar / Laquan Green / J. White Did It / Dieuson Octave / Klenord Raphael / Jordan Thorpe / Jermaine White"
                songName="Bodak Yellow" sku="K315SPR19A004" albumref="K315SPR19A" type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="5" songlength="3:30"
                songcomposersandwriters="Belcalis Almanzar / Alan Bergman / Marilyn Bergman / Dennis Coles / Robert Diggs / Adam Feeney / Gary Grice / Marvin Hamlisch / Lamont Hawkins / Anderson Hernandez / Lauryn Hill / Jason Hunter / Russell Jones / Matthew Samuels / Clifford Smith / Jordan Thorpe / U-God / Corey Woods"
                songName="Be Careful" sku="K315SPR19A005" albumref="K315SPR19A" type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="6" songlength="4:44"
                songcomposersandwriters="Belcalis Almanzar / Chancelor Bennett / Allen Ritter / Matthew Samuels"
                songName="Best Life" sku="K315SPR19A006" albumref="K315SPR19A" type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="7" songlength="4:13"
                songcomposersandwriters="Belcalis Almanzar / José Álvaro Osorio Balvin / Benito Antonio Martinez Ocasio / Tony Pabon / Manny Rodriguez"
                songName="I Like It" sku="K315SPR19A007" albumref="K315SPR19A" type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="8" songlength="2:57"
                songcomposersandwriters="Belcalis Almanzar / Khari Cain / Nija Charles / Kehlani Parrish / Mike Riley"
                songName="Ring" sku="K315SPR19A008" albumref="K315SPR19A" type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="9" songlength="3:49"
                songcomposersandwriters="Belcalis Almanzar / Jordan Thorpe / Jermaine White"
                songName="Money Bag" sku="K315SPR19A009" albumref="K315SPR19A" type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="10" songlength="3:44"
                songcomposersandwriters="Shayaa Bin Abraham-Joseph / Belcalis Almanzar / Samuel Gloade / Darryl McCorkell"
                songName="Bartier Cardi (feat. 21 Savage)" sku="K315SPR19A010"
                albumref="K315SPR19A" type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="11" songlength="3:50"
                songcomposersandwriters="Belcalis Almanzar / Keenon Jackson / Leslie Andre Wakefield Jr. / Dijon McFarlane"
                songName="She Bad" sku="K315SPR19A011" albumref="K315SPR19A" type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="12" songlength="3:08"
                songcomposersandwriters="Belcalis Almanzar / Benjamin Levin / Alexandra Tamposi / Justin Tranter / Andrew Wotman"
                songName="Thru Your Phone" sku="K315SPR19A012" albumref="K315SPR19A" type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="13" songlength="3:20"
                songcomposersandwriters="Belcalis Almanzar / Nija Charles / Kevin Gomringer / Tim Gomringer / Shane Lindstrom / Solana Rowe"
                songName="I Do" sku="K315SPR19A013" albumref="K315SPR19A" type="song"> </song>
        </Songs>
        <producersMixersSongwritersEngineers>
            <engineersMixers> Leslie Brathwaite &amp; Evan LaRay </engineersMixers>
            <songwriters> Belcalis Almanzar &amp; Jorden Thorpe </songwriters>
            <masteringEngineer> Colin Leonard </masteringEngineer>
        </producersMixersSongwritersEngineers>
    </album>
</artist>

<artist personorgroup="person" groupmembernames="N/A" artistorgroupcountry="United States"
    careerBegin="2004" careerend="N/A" artistName="Brandi Carlile" genre="Pop/Rock">

    <album albumCategory="Grammy_Nominee" albumName="By The Way, I Forgive You" sku="K315SPR19B"
        type="album">
        <Comment> Haven't listened, not my taste </Comment>

        <Rating> 11/13 </Rating>

        <albumArt> Brandi Carlile.jpg <!-- Found from albumartexchange.com -->
        </albumArt>

        <releases>
            <release release="By the Way, I Forgive You" releasedate="2018-02-16"
                recordlabel="Elektra (1950–1989, revived 2009–06-01; read annotations before use), Low Country Sound"
                recordlabelcatalognumber="565226-2" barcodenumber="075678659188" country="US"
                format="CD"> </release>
            <release release="By the Way, I Forgive You (mastered for iTunes)"
                releasedate="2018-02-16"
                recordlabel="Elektra (1950–1989, revived 2009–06-01; read annotations before use)"
                recordlabelcatalognumber="N/A" barcodenumber="075679885449" country="US"
                format="Digital Media"> </release>
        </releases>
        <Songs>
            <song songposition="1" songlength="4:01"
                songcomposersandwriters="Brandi Carlile / Phil Hanseroth / Tim Hanseroth"
                songName="Everytime I Hear That Song" sku="K315SPR19B001" albumref="K315SPR19B"
                type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="2" songlength="4:39"
                songcomposersandwriters="Brandi Carlile / Dave Cobb / Phil Hanseroth / Tim Hanseroth"
                songName="The Joke" sku="K315SPR19B002" albumref="K315SPR19B" type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="3" songlength="4:22"
                songcomposersandwriters="Brandi Carlile / Phil Hanseroth / Tim Hanseroth"
                songName="Hold Out Your Hand" sku="K315SPR19B003" albumref="K315SPR19B"
                type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="4" songlength="3:16"
                songcomposersandwriters="Brandi Carlile / Phil Hanseroth / Tim Hanseroth"
                songName="The Mother" sku="K315SPR19B004" albumref="K315SPR19B" type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="5" songlength="4:07"
                songcomposersandwriters="Brandi Carlile / Phil Hanseroth / Tim Hanseroth"
                songName="Whatever You Do" sku="K315SPR19B005" albumref="K315SPR19B" type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="6" songlength="4:43"
                songcomposersandwriters="Brandi Carlile / Phil Hanseroth / Tim Hanseroth"
                songName="Fulton County Jane Doe" sku="K315SPR19B006" albumref="K315SPR19B"
                type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="7" songlength="4:28"
                songcomposersandwriters="Brandi Carlile / Phil Hanseroth / Tim Hanseroth"
                songName="Sugartooth" sku="K315SPR19B007" albumref="K315SPR19B" type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="8" songlength="3:51"
                songcomposersandwriters="Brandi Carlile / Phil Hanseroth / Tim Hanseroth"
                songName="Most of All" sku="K315SPR19B008" albumref="K315SPR19B" type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="9" songlength="4:06"
                songcomposersandwriters="Brandi Carlile / Phil Hanseroth / Tim Hanseroth"
                songName="Harder to Forgive" sku="K315SPR19B009" albumref="K315SPR19B"
                type="song"> </song>
            <song songposition="10" songlength="5:47"
                songcomposersandwriters="Brandi Carlile / Phil Hanseroth / Tim Hanseroth"
                songName="Party of One" sku="K315SPR19B10" albumref="K315SPR19B" type="song"
             > </song>
            </Songs>
            <producersMixersSongwritersEngineers>
            <producers> Dave Cobb &amp; Shooter Jennings </producers>
            <engineersMixers> Dave Cobb &amp; Eddie Spear 
</engineersMixers>
            <songwriters> Brandi Carlile, Phil Hanseroth &amp; Tim 
Hanseroth </songwriters>
                <masteringEngineer> Pete Lyman </masteringEngineer>
           </producersMixersSongwritersEngineers>
       </album>
    </artist>
```

Schema Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:element name="personorgroup" type="xs:string"> </xs:element>
<xs:element name="groupmembernames" type="xs:string"> </xs:element>
<xs:element name="artistorgroupcountry" type="xs:string"> 
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="careerBegin" type="xs:string"> </xs:element>
<xs:element name="careerend" type="xs:string"> </xs:element>
<xs:element name="artistName" type="xs:string"> </xs:element>
<xs:element name="genre" type="xs:string"> </xs:element>
<xs:element name="artist">
    <xs:complexType>
           <xs:sequence>
               <xs:element ref="artist"> 

               </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: My schema code might me absolutely useless, I really have no idea what to do...

Comment: Yes, your scheme does not match your XML example, and your XML example does not match the description you gave as you don't seem to have Group Members, or is that the groupmembernames?   Also you might want to look at the difference between elements and attributes.   Can you give a full valid XML example of what you want?  As you are missing a few closing tags.

Comment: so this is for all the grammy nominees this year and my professor had us have an option for groupmembernames if the attribute before was listed as group however none were groups

Comment: So was the XML given to you by the professor or did you make it up? Because that XML would not be suitable for the Group Members requirement.

Comment: I made it. Honestly I have no idea how to write the schema for it.

Comment: • Artist or group: string values; required
• Group members: string value, this can occur once, more than once or not at all
• Genre: string value, must occur at least once per Artist or group; required 
• Producers: string value, this can occur once, more than once or not at all

Comment: Examples of what I have to do with my edited code above^

Comment: If you want something to occur more than once, then you usually would not make it an attribute, like you have done with groupmember names.  Unless you get your XML structure correct for that first, your schema is not going to work.  Make it an element like comment or rating.

Comment: DO you think you can write a mock schema using the instructions I was given?

Comment: Yes, it is not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

For your XML example the following schema would describe it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Albums">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="artist">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="album">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="Comment" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="Rating" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="albumArt" type="xs:string" />
                    <xs:element name="releases">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="release">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:simpleContent>
                                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                  <xs:attribute name="release" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                  <xs:attribute name="releasedate" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                  <xs:attribute name="recordlabel" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                  <xs:attribute name="recordlabelcatalognumber" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                  <xs:attribute name="barcodenumber" type="xs:unsignedLong" use="required" />
                                  <xs:attribute name="country" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                  <xs:attribute name="format" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                </xs:extension>
                              </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="Songs">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="song">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:simpleContent>
                                <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                  <xs:attribute name="songposition" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
                                  <xs:attribute name="songlength" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                  <xs:attribute name="songcomposersandwriters" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                  <xs:attribute name="songName" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                  <xs:attribute name="sku" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                  <xs:attribute name="albumref" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                  <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                                </xs:extension>
                              </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="producersMixersSongwritersEngineers">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="producers" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element name="engineersMixers" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element name="songwriters" type="xs:string" />
                          <xs:element name="masteringEngineer" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="albumCategory" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                  <xs:attribute name="albumName" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                  <xs:attribute name="sku" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                  <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="personorgroup" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="groupmembernames" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="artistorgroupcountry" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="careerBegin" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="careerend" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="artistName" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="genre" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

However that would not match the requirements that you were given as to Artist or Group, and the Group Member

For that you want something more like the below, where you can either have a record for an artist or a group, and in the group you have an element for memberName that can occur multiple times.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Albums">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="artist">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="album" type="AlbumType" />
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:attribute name="artistName" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="artistcountry" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="careerBegin" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="careerend" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="genre" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="group">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="memberName" type="xs:string" />
                <xs:element name="album" type="AlbumType" />
              </xs:sequence>
              <xs:attribute name="artistName" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="groupBegin" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="groupEnd" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="genre" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              <xs:attribute name="groupcountry" type="xs:string" use="required" />
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:complexType name="AlbumType">
    <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="Comment" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="Rating" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="albumArt" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="releases">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="release">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                  <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="release" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="releasedate" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="recordlabel" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="recordlabelcatalognumber" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="barcodenumber" type="xs:unsignedLong" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="country" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="format" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                  </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Songs">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="song">
              <xs:complexType>
                <xs:simpleContent>
                  <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                    <xs:attribute name="songposition" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="songlength" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="songcomposersandwriters" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="songName" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="sku" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="albumref" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                  </xs:extension>
                </xs:simpleContent>
              </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="producersMixersSongwritersEngineers">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="producers" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="engineersMixers" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="songwriters" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="masteringEngineer" type="xs:string" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="albumCategory" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="albumName" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="sku" type="xs:string" use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```